# Laravel request()->all() is empty in booted function when running tests

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-testing

I created a trait sets up some Global Scopes based on the query parameters.

It does that by reading from the `request()` helper and reading the query parameters from the url. Below is the start of the trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait QueryParamScopes {

    // Todo: add limit and offset functionality.
    // Todo: Add functionality to always return a maximum no. results. add pagination for retrieving.
    // Todo: add wherehas functionality.

    protected static function bootQueryParamScopes() // Todo: write tests
    {
        dd(request()->all()); // this returns []

        $queryParams = static::getQueryParamsByRequest();

        static::handleWhereParams($queryParams['where']);
        static::handleWithParams($queryParams['with']);
        static::handleOrderByParams($queryParams['orderBy']);
        static::handleAppendsParams($queryParams['appends']);
    }
```

All works as expected but when writing testcases the `request()->all()` function returns `[]`;

My models use the trait above. In my test I call an endpoint that retrieves the model using

```
$response = $this->getJson('/v0.1/zipcodes?with[]=dealer');
```

So I expect `request()-all()` to return `[with => ['dealer']]`

Another strange thing is that it is only empty in the trait (maybe because it's all static methods?) when I `dd(request()->all())` from the controller method it outputs the query parameters as expected.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here, or how to overcome this.

Comment: What do you expect `request()->all()` would return in your test cases? From where would it return that?

Comment: Hi @N69S, I've edited the question to include the answers to your questions. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: and where would `[with => ['dealer']]` come from, are you not starting your tests from CLI command?

Comment: It comes from the uri 
$response = $this->getJson('/v0.1/zipcodes?with[]=dealer');
calls the URL

Answer (score 0):

In your function `bootQueryParamScopes()` it's null because you aren't accepting request. It should be...

```
function bootQueryParamScopes(Request $request)
```

Also make sure at the top of the trait you have...

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: As an afterthought you could just pass what you need from the controller too. Since you  probably are using request on the controller action. Just pass the variable you need sorted to your trait.  And now that I'm looking you aren't really doing anything in your trait.  Your trait should return a value back to your controller action.

Comment: I do not have to pass anything when using the request helper function, right? Shouldn't that resolve the Request object from the service container

Comment: Also the code works, only not when testing